# Interpreting Complex Number Results in Quantum State Discrimination

Tags: qiskit, openpulse

I have a question regarding the explanation in [qiskit pulse](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-quantum-hardware/calibrating-qubits-pulse.html#3.2-Determining-0-vs-1-). The results are displayed as in the figure, with the following code:

```python
gnd_exc_results = job.result(timeout=120)

gnd_results = gnd_exc_results.get_memory(0)[:, qubit]*scale_factor
exc_results = gnd_exc_results.get_memory(1)[:, qubit]*scale_factor

plt.figure()

# Plot all the results
# All results from the ground state are plotted in blue
plt.scatter(np.real(gnd_results), np.imag(gnd_results), 
                s=5, cmap='viridis', c='blue', alpha=0.5, label='state_0')
# All results from the excited state are plotted in red
plt.scatter(np.real(exc_results), np.imag(exc_results), 
                s=5, cmap='viridis', c='red', alpha=0.5, label='state_1')

plt.axis('square')

# Plot a large dot for the average result of the 0 and 1 states.
mean_gnd = np.mean(gnd_results) # takes mean of both real and imaginary parts
mean_exc = np.mean(exc_results)
plt.scatter(np.real(mean_gnd), np.imag(mean_gnd), 
            s=200, cmap='viridis', c='black',alpha=1.0, label='state_0_mean')
plt.scatter(np.real(mean_exc), np.imag(mean_exc), 
            s=200, cmap='viridis', c='black',alpha=1.0, label='state_1_mean')

plt.ylabel('I [a.u.]', fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel('Q [a.u.]', fontsize=15)
plt.title("0-1 discrimination", fontsize=15)

plt.show()
```

[image: result]

My questions are as follows: Why are the results complex numbers? What physical quantity do these complex number values correspond to? And related to this, do the measurement results have units of energy?"

Comment: It is because of two orthogonal components within the signal- [In-phase and quadrature components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-phase_and_quadrature_components). So, we use complex numbers to represent it.